# Is possible to have a Front Matter header in a script?

Tags: python-3.x, file, scripting, metadata, yaml-front-matter

I was thinking in how to include some *metadata* in my script files in a way that other scripts could process this information without interfering in its `./` execution.

YAML Front Matter came to my mind, but obviously its `---` syntax produce error either in `#!/bin/bash` as in `#!/usr/bin/python3`, for example.

1. Is there some simple way to allow a non-comment block (as Front Metter's one) to be ignored by script `./` execution?
2. Or any other known way to make a file carry some metadatas possible to be accessed anyway without interfer in its generic execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a comment, you could use a Python object of some kind.

This is a bit like the way doctstrings work in Python: The string is an expression but it's evaluation doesn't have side effects and Python uses it as metadata.

However if you need a shebang (`#!...`) that does have to come first. Your metadata processor will have to skip that line.